# How to click Label element using watir?

Tags: watir

We have check box rendering as `<label for ="">` element. I am facing issue to select it.

**Rendered HTML code:**

```
<label for="copyFromCheckbox"> </label>
```

How I am trying to click:

```
@browser.label(:text,'copyFromCheckbox').parent.checkbox.set  **// Not working**
@browser.label(:text,'copyFromCheckbox').click                **//Not working**
```

**My latest outcome**

The following is html rendered code:

```
<label for="JobReport"><span class="Radiobox-txt">  Job Report (only one report that covers the whole job, view <a href="exampleJobReport.html">example report</a>) </span></label>
```

I have tried following ways but no success in either case. Messe " unable to locate element is coming in all cases.

**Method 1:**

```
sleep 3
@browser.span(:text,'Job Report (only one report that covers the whole job, view').parent.click
```

**Method 2**

```
sleep 3 
@browser.span(:xpath,'/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/span').parent.click
```

**Method 3**

```
@browser.span(:xpath,'/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/span').when_present.click
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "not working" means? Is there an exception? What does it do? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i am able to fix this problem by using following line of code. It is working absolutely fine for me.

```
@browser.span(:text, /^Job Report/).parent.click
```

Thanks everybody for sharing some possible ways.

Cheers.
Ray

Comment: I was going to suggests a regular expression. Seems like you already figured that out. Good work. Also, with Method 2 and Method 3, for future reference if you are using the XPath there is no real need to use `.parent`. Instead you would just want to try `@browser.label(:xpath,'/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label').click`. I.e., go straight for the `<label>` element.

Answer (score 1):

The `:for` attribute is not supported by Watir for the `<label>` tag. See https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir

`@browser.label(:text,'copyFromCheckbox').click` would not work because `copyFromCheckbox` is not `:text` but is rather the aforementioned, non-supported `:for` attribute.

Is there text inside the `<label>` tag?

For example,

```
<label for='copyFromCheckbox'>Hello</label>
```

could be clicked by

```
@browser.label(:text,'Hello').click
```

Alternately, you could find the XPath for the label and click using that.

For example,

```
@browser.label(:xpath,'<insert XPath here>').click
```

Comment: What if you have this rendered code <label for='copyFromCheckbox'><span class= "abc">Hello</span></label>

Comment: To click the `label` tag, you could do `@browser.span(:text, 'Hello').parent.click` or `@browser.span(:class, 'abc').parent.click` if those are specific enough for your page. If not you will just need to get the XPath for the `label` as I described above.

Comment: i have updated my question to add my latest outcome. please check.